# Fourier Transform for $f(t) = e^{-t}\cdot\sin(t)$ from "MajorPrep" Video about Laplace Tansformations

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

So I just watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2y7n6jw5d0) about the Laplace transformation and I wanted to follow along on the steps. Timestamp is $3:14$.
In the beginning he starts out with a fourier transformation of this function: $$f(t) = e^{-t} \cdot \sin(t)$$
He goes on to say that this is pretty easy using integration by parts and viewing $i$ as a constant. So far so good.
This is the expected outcome of the Fourier transform:
$$ X(\omega) = \frac{1}{1+(1+i\omega)^2} $$

So I try the fourier transform like this:
$$X(\omega) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \cdot \sin(t) \cdot e^{-i\omega t} dt$$
simplify
$$X(\omega) = \int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \sin(t) dt$$ 
first integration by parts
$$X(\omega) = e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (-\cos(t)) - (i \omega +1) \int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \cos(t) dt$$ 
So far so good, lets go for the second round
$$X(\omega) = e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (-\cos(t)) - (i \omega +1) \cdot ( e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (-\sin(t)) -(i\omega+1)\int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \sin(t) dt)$$ 
Now the last part is the same as the Equation we started out with and we get
$$X(\omega) = \frac{-e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\cos(t)) + (i \omega +1) \cdot ( e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\sin(t))}{(i\omega+1)^2}$$

> How do I get from this to here 
>   $$ X(\omega) = \frac{1}{1+(1+i\omega)^2}~? $$

I mean the $(i\omega+1)^2$ part looks promising but I am quite rusty in calculus. Is it a special property of the Fourier transform i have to use? Because lots of fourier transforms have 1's in them. from what i have gathered. I tried playing around with eulers identity but so far no luck.

Help me, please and thank you.

EDIT : The Function $f(t)$ is only defined from $0$ to $\infty$

EDIT 2 : So i guess it should go something like this:

$$X(\omega) = \frac{[-e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\cos(t))]_0^\infty + (i \omega +1) \cdot [( e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\sin(t))]_0^\infty}{(i\omega+1)^2}$$

How am I supposed to evaluate $cos (\infty)$, that is non existant.

EDIT 3:
Ok, so the first [] is $$
[-e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\cos(t))]_0^\infty 
$$
makes
$$ 0 - 1 = -1 $$
 The second [] is just 0 which means that the solo $(1+i\omega)$ vanishes

So the whole thing just becomes:
$$ \frac{1}{(i\omega+1)^2} $$

EDIT 4:

If I go from here: $$ X(\omega) = [e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (-\cos(t))]_0^\infty - (i \omega +1) \cdot [( e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (-\sin(t)) ]_0^\infty-(i\omega+1)\int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \sin(t) dt)$$ 
which is to make it a little clearer 
$$X(\omega) = 1 - (i \omega +1) \cdot 0 -(i\omega+1)^2\int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \sin(t) dt$$

which is $$X(\omega) = 1 - (i \omega +1) \cdot 0 -(i\omega+1)^2 X(\omega)$$

So I bring $-(i\omega+1)^2 X(\omega)$ to the other side of the =
I factorize and bring anything that is not $X(\omega)$ back again which gives me

$$X(\omega) = \frac{1-0}{(i\omega+1)^2 } $$

EDIT5: I'm dumb and made a mistake in my head in the last step. Good night yall.

Comment: Why did you take Fourier from 0 to $\infty$  and not from $-\infty$?

Comment: There is a lot going on with lots of misinformation, so I'll try to keep this brief. A fourier transform goes on the whole real line. This is actually a one sided Laplace transform evaluated on the imaginary axis in the $s$ plane (there is a difference between the two, especially when considering transform properties). Second, when you do an integral w.r.t. a variable, that variable should not be present at the end. Your final answer has $t$'s, which means you did not plug them in when you were supposed to.

Comment: @Isham The Function is only defined from 0 to plus infinity.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ok i will read some more on the laplace transform and the s plane. However I am unsure where exactly I am I supposed to actually evaluate the integral. I mean it just vanishes because I set the first equation equal to my second to last equation and i can cancel all the integrals.

Comment: Ok I see but you didnt evaluate the integral since you have a definite integral in your first step of integration by part. You still have cosine function ...Evaluate your integrals when you perfrom by part integration

Comment: In fact the biggest mistake you made is to consider the definite integral as an indefinite one.

Comment: Geez, Thank you I have been tanking a year long brake from studies to take care of a relative. Apparently i forgot how to partially integrate correctly^^ I will do it and post an update if you don't mind.

Comment: @Isham I hope I am not asking too many questions but I am quite rusty in maths it seems. How am I supposed to evaluate a cos(inifity)? That is not defined. Or do i somehow use the property of $\omega$ as 2pif for my evaluation?

Comment: The exponential at the denominator goes to infinity so the fraction is zero $$\frac {\cos t }{e^{t(1+iw)}}\big |_0^\infty=0-(\cos(0)/e^0)$$ evaluate at zero now

Comment: at 0 its just $1/1$ so the whole first [] is just a -1. If i keep going like that on the second [] that just becomes a 0 for the whole term so in the end I get $\frac{-1}{(i\omega+1)^2}$ @Isham

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103366/discussion-between-electrified-and-isham).

Comment: It should not vanish since you get the original integral you started with, just put it on the left side. Factorize.

Comment: @Isham nevermind, i just did the factorization wrong. Thank you very much for you help. I hope I did not annoy you 2 much with my questions :)

Comment: No yw Electrified. I am happy if it helped you to get the right answer.

Comment: After performing two integration by part you end with the orifinal integral. You factorize and deduce the final answer.

Comment: To note, MajorPrep's channel has been rebranded as "Zach Star."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$X(\omega) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \cdot \sin(t) \cdot e^{-i\omega t} dt$$
Integrating by part:
$$X(\omega) = [-e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\cos(t))]_0^\infty - (i \omega +1)( \int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \cos(t) dt)$$
$$
[-e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\cos(t))]_0^\infty=0\color{red}{+1} 
$$
The evaluation in the first by part integration is $+1$ not $-1$
$$X(\omega) = 1 - (i \omega +1)( \int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \cos(t) dt)$$
Since as you wrote in the comment:
$$
[e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot (\sin(t))]_0^\infty=0 
$$
We have that:
$$X(\omega) = 1 - (i \omega +1)^2 \cdot ( \int_0^\infty  e^{-i\omega t - t} \cdot \sin(t) dt)$$

$$X(\omega) = 1 - (i \omega +1)^2 X(\omega) $$
Put the integral on the left side and factorize:

$$X(\omega)(1+(i \omega +1)^2 ) = 1 $$
$$\implies X(\omega)=\frac 1 {1+(i \omega +1)^2 }$$